# GCC: mixed C/assembly project - include directive

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, include, c-preprocessor

I have a huge project consisting of:

- `main.c` which contains main function and calls function from `abc.S` - nothing more!
- `abc.S` which does some initialization steps and then calls other assembly routines
- `a1.S`, `a2.S`, ... which contain functions called by `abc.S`

`abc.S` has all the files included like this:

```
.include "a1.S"
.include "a2.S"
.include "a3.S"
```

Now I want to include a file called `definitions.h` which contains some `define MEOW 123` and I want to use `MEOW` in e.g. `a1.S` - how does my makefile have to look like to achieve this behaviour? Where do I have to include `definitions.h`?

I tried a few things but ended up having nothing but errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out for myself - makefile could look like this:

```
all:
            gcc -o abc a1.S a2.S a3.S abc.S main.c
clean:
            rm -rf abc
```

Include `definitions.h` in `a1.S` and include `a1.S` in `abc.S`.